# Javascript - Save just a part of an input value to localStorage

Tags: javascript, input, local-storage

I have a page where the user is asked his name and will have to type it in a textbox.

I want him to be able to type a full sentence like "my name is John Doe" and be greeted with something like "Hello, John Doe. Welcome to this page".

I managed to accomplish that by ignoring word combinations from the input, like "my name is", "I am" and "I'm". The remaining of the input will most likely be the user's name.

My question now is, how do I save the user name to localStorage, to use it later, on a different page? I cannot save everything the user types. That would get me something like "Welcome back, my name is John Doe".

I want to save only the words that remain after the replacements.

This is what I have:

```js
function myFunction() {
            var text;
            var answers = document.getElementById("userInput").value.toLowerCase();
            answers = answers.replace(/[^a-z0-9' ]/g, "");
            answers = answers.replace("my name is", "");
            answers = answers.replace("i am", "");
            answers = answers.replace("i'm", "");
            switch (answers) {
                case "":
                    text = "Please tell me your name.";
                    break;
                default:
                    text = "Hello, " + CapitalizeName(answers) + ". Welcome to this page.";
            }
            document.getElementById("greeting").innerHTML = text;
            document.getElementById("userInput").value = "";
            localStorage.setItem("userName", CapitalizeName(answers));
        }

        function CapitalizeName(name) {
            let _array = name.split(" ");
            let n_array = [];
            _array.map(w => {
                w = w.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + w.slice(1);
                n_array.push(w);
            });
            return n_array.join(" ");
        }
```

```html
<p>What is your name?</p>
    <input id="userInput" type="text" spellcheck="false" autofocus onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) myFunction();">
    <p id="greeting"></p>
```

On the second page, I have this:

```js
localStorage.getItem("userName");

document.getElementById("helloUser").innerHTML = "Welcome back " + userName + "!";
```

```html
<p id="helloUser"></p>
```

My guess is that I am not saving it the right way. I tried searching for solutions online, but I cannot find anything that specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work on your whole domain.

Note that it doesn't in the example for security reason (blocked).

```js
data.onchange = (function(){
  localStorage.setItem("userName", data.value)
})
var userName = localStorage.getItem("userName");

document.getElementById("helloUser").innerHTML = "Welcome back " + userName + "!";
```

```html
<input id="data">
<p id="helloUser"></p>
```

Comment: If it works fine, you will find the value in your browser inspector, «storage» tab. ? 
So to test out, from the console: `localStorage.setItem("userName", "test")` must create the entry in the storage tab?

Comment: This works perfectly! thank you very much for your help, mate!

Comment: I had some syntax errors the first time I tried your solution. It's fixed now. Thank you very much!